# Group by Difference Between Rows SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I have a table `values` with following format, I would a SQL query that will count the differences in time for the `Clock` **the column `delta clock` does not exist, but is added to make the example easier to follow**

```
RID | Clock | delta clock ( result of lead(Clock,1) OVER(ORDER BY Clock) - Clock )
0     0       2
1     2       4
2     6       2
3     8       2
4     10      4
5     14      2
6     16      2
7     18      NULL
```

What I'm Looking for should be something like

```
Select lead(Clock,1) OVER(ORDER BY Clock) - Clock AS "Step" , count(*)
From values
Group by Step
```

And would return

```
Step | count
2      5
4      2
Null   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the values of the column `Clock` are always increasing, you can aggregate after you get the differences:

```
SELECT Step, COUNT(*) Count
FROM (
  SELECT LEAD(Clock) OVER(ORDER BY Clock) - Clock AS Step
  FROM [values]
)
GROUP BY Step
ORDER BY Step IS NULL, Step
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7FJRMkDXSn1sob5TCVKqK7/0).
Results:

```
| Step | Count |
| ---- | ----- |
| 2    | 5     |
| 4    | 2     |
|      | 1     |
```